# Overwatch Origin skins from loot boxes

Tags: overwatch

Can you get the skins that come with the Origins edition of Overwatch from loot boxes or are the exclusive to the Origins edition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From an interview with [Jeff Kaplan](http://www.pcgamer.com/jeff-kaplan-talks-overwatch-progression-unlocks-and-beta-invites/),

> Similarly, while there's currently no “purchase-only” content in the game beyond the Origins Edition and Widowmaker preorder skins [those won't be unlockable for credits because, he said, “We want those to feel special and exclusive”], it's simply too early in the process to commit to it one way or the other.

The answer is you cannot unlock them with credits.

Comment: I want Noire widowmaker so bad but I didn't expect to like this game T_T

Comment: The hair on the Noire model looks super weird- I actually prefer the Countess skin. To each his own I guess :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't get them from loot boxes, they are exclusive to the Origins edition.